# Sending login credentials in a HTTP header to a secure server

Tags: java, security, authentication, ldap, jetty

There is a module 'Module1' that authenticates a user using LDAP. The module has a class  that has to make an http request to another remote service using the same login ldap credentials.

I have the LDAP class that implements the authentication in the remote service.

I do not know how to send the login credentials from Module1 to the remote service in the http header. How can I access the credentials which i used for Ldap login from Module1 programatically ?  Your responses will be very much appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for Basic Authentication , in which the user credentials will be encoded and send through the Header . Do insure to  secure the call from Module1 to the remote service , so essentially the call from Module1 to Remote Service will happen over HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LDAP, the authentication can be passed off like Basic. If you know the username and password, append the header "Authorization" with the value "Basic base64_token".

The base64 token is a string that is base64 encoded with your username and password in the format username:password. Ideally, this should work. Let me know if it doesn't work. In that case, we can explore options using SPNEGO.

Code for LDAP in JAVA:

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //Replace username and password with your username and password
    token = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes())
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) endpoint.openConnection();

    // Set the necessary header fields, which in this case is Basic
    conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + token);

   //Continue to do what you want to do after this. This should authenticate 
  // you to the server
  }
}
```